# Why am I getting the same Image id from different Image view in a repeater?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repeater

I have a repeater that slide shows images from a folder, such that when you click on the current image in the slide, a product page is opened that shows the details information of the selected image.
Meanwhile, I have a productModel that list all the images from the database, such that when you click on any of the images it opens the image product page as above.
Now, my concern is that the hyperlink I attached to the repeater keeps opening the same product page from different image that appears on the repeater. Could anyone please help me point out what I am doing wrong? I will be most grateful!

```
<ul class="bjqs">
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">  
<ItemTemplate><li>
<asp:HyperLink ID="link" runat="server">                       
<img src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Value") %>' 
  title='<%# (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Text").ToString()).Split('.')[0].ToString() %>' alt=""> 
   </asp:HyperLink></li>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

The Server side code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillPage();
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/pages/Management/Images/Products/"));
        List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {             
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);   
            files.Add(new ListItem(fileName, "/pages/Management/Images/Products/" + fileName));
        }
        Repeater1.DataSource = files;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{

        ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
    List<Product> products = productModel.GetAllProducts();

    foreach (Product product in products)
    {
        Panel productPanel = new Panel();        
        HyperLink hp = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("link");
        hp.NavigateUrl = "~/pages/Product.aspx?id=" + product.ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you getting a new list of products and looping through them in your ItemDatabound event?  I'm not sure what you're doing, but from a cursory glance it looks like there is a fundamental misuse of the ItemDataBound event.

Comment: Could you please identify where I went wrong?

Comment: I cannot help you too much because I don't really know what you're trying to do.  The ItemDataBound event will fire for every individual item in your files list (whatever you are binding to).  You can access each item in the RepeaterItemEventArgs e to get what you want from it.  Apparently all you are binding to is a string object with the file name.  Perhaps you want to bind to the list of Products, then attach each product to a file?  Really it is up to you.  Hopefully understanding the repeater and the ItemDataBound event will help you figure out what you want to do better.

Comment: Your analysis is insightful and helpful Adam, Actually each product in the db is replicated in a directory, and as you have rightly stated, I wish to bind to the list of Products. The problem is that I dont know if what I am doing is achievable as I am using Images from the folder for the repeater and I want each of these images to open a Product page created from the db using a productModel.when clicked.

Comment: I am sorry for my naivety, I am not a pro on Repeaters. I have remove the foreach  and it helps. However, I keep getting the same url when clicked on any current Image without any product id value being passed "http://localhost:1051/pages/Product.aspx?id=" Can you give me head up on how to use the if statement to find the right products from folder to match the row i am on?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillPage();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GetData(null, null, null, null);  
    }

    DbRetrival();

}


protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{

    string ID = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "ID").ToString();
    HyperLink hp = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("link");
        hp.NavigateUrl = "~/pages/Product.aspx?id=" + ID ;

}


private void DbRetrival()
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SuperStoreDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("Select ID,Image,Name from Product",con );
    adp.Fill(dt);

        Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}

private void FolderRetrival()
{
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/pages/Management/Images/Products/"));
    List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
    foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    {

        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        files.Add(new ListItem(fileName, "/pages/Management/Images/Products/" + fileName));
    }
    Repeater1.DataSource = files;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```

The asp page:

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server"  OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">

<ItemTemplate>
    <li>

    <asp:HyperLink ID="link" runat="server">                       
        <br /> <asp:Image  runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"~/pages/Management/Images/Products/" + String.Format("{0}",
                Eval("Image")) %>' Width='180px' Height='145px' /> </Image>
      <br />  <%# Eval("Name")%>

    </asp:HyperLink>
      </li>
   </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have the same Link for every item in your repeater is that when you bind an item to the repeater every single item runs the ItemDataBound event.  Inside that event you loop through every Product item and overwrite the HyperLink NavigateURL over and over in the foreach loop until the LAST product in the list is the remaining value for the hyperlink.

If you set a breakpoint and step through the ItemDataBound event you will see this behavior.

I cannot tell you how to fix it because I simply do not see how you intend to map a file to a Product.  Once you do that I would suggest bind your repeater to the Product list and add a public property to your Product model which will hold the file location of the image you wish to show.  This could then be set in the ItemDataBound event or in the aspx markup as you are doing now with the src for instance.

Some info on the ItemDataBoundEvent including how to get the underlying data item.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you Adam, at least you make me realize that it is difficult to map file to a Product, which leaves me with no option than to look for other alternatives to achieve my aim. Without using the file system approach, is there anyway I can create a slide show (Image and label) from the db? If yes I will appreciate some samples.

Comment: On a second thought, is there a way I can add a label that has the product id and use Eval to set the value. Then in itemdatabound event find the control and set the url of the hyperlink?